# Как указать ID текущей записи в условиях отбора в запросе ACCESS?

Tags: access, ms-access

На форме будет кнопка Добавить врача.
Она копирует текущий ID и спрашивает код специализации и вносит это все в таблицу Врачи.
[image: Форма]

[image: Схема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если Персона есть суть врач, то таблица построена неверно: при увольнении старой персоны и приёме новой - Вы не сможете переопределить её как врача, т.к отношение 1:1. Внесите в таблицу Персоны данные о Враче (это не усложнить Вашу базу).
Соответственно дополнительная индексация по Специализации нужна. Специализацию в этом случае выводим на форму как раскрывающийся список. Еще добавил бы поле active для работающих врачей (для последующей фильтрации "только работающие").Тогда не потребуется городить огород, который Вы запланировали.